# Test Café not redirecting to external site

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to test the connection between two websites. To do so, I need to click through some wizard on website one, which will then open a new tab and redirects to another website inside this new tab.

The new tab opens, but the redirect does not work. It works if I do it manually without Test Café.

So my questions are

1. is there some (undocumented?) security mechanism to prevent redirects to external sites? (and how do I shut this off?)
2. what could be the issue if this is no security feature?

Any help appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> is there some (undocumented?) security mechanism to prevent redirects to external sites? (and how do I shut this off?)

There are no such security mechanisms.

> what could be the issue if this is no security feature?

It's difficult to say anything specific about the cause of the issue right now. If you can prepare a [simple example](https://testcafe.io/402636/faq#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue), please create an [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml) in the TestCafe Github repository and share it here.

Comment: Thank you, I switched to Playwright.